# Trying to orderby with case when clause for MultiDocumentQuery?

Tags: kentico

I am trying to get all my pagetypes from kentico, but I would like to order them by all the page types that starts with the letter "F", first and then the other pages alphabetically.

What I am trying is:

`1) MultiDocumentQuery docQuery = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Type("forms").OnSite(SiteContext.CurrentSiteID).Published(); 
2) docQuery.OrderBy("FormName");`

But what I need is to order em using something like this (SQL):

`SELECT FormName
FROM Forms
order by
  case when FormName like 'C%' then 0 else 1 end,
  FormName`

What I cant do is to translate the `case when` properly to c#, and implement it to docQuery.
So the result should be for example,:

1. Form1
2. Form2
3. Form3
4. A...
5. B...

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd look at adding your **case** statement in the **columns** rather then the **where** like this:

```
CASE WHEN FormName LIKE 'F%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsForm
```

This way you can have a new column called IsForm and can have an **Order by** of:

```
IsForm, FormName
```